# Animate height when max-height is changed to none

Tags: html, css

On my website I want to animate when a menu opens. I do that by changing the `max-height` of the `<div>` that is the menu (and also changing `display`).

`max-height` is changed from `4em` to `none`.
It used to be that it was changed to `500px` instead of `none` and then the animation did work, however it doesn't work with `none`.

What am I doing wrong?

[Here is my website](https://jsfiddle.net/x84n04pa/1/)

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @kauffee000 it is at the «Here is my website»-link at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score -1):

None is not valid for max-height. I would change it to 0.

Comment: What I want is that if I click the button to open the menu it should be able to get as much height as it needs to display all the content so I want to remove the limit of the maximal height. Setting it to 0 would mean that it has no height at all.

Comment: **A few things:**

1) You'll get down-voted for sure if you don't post actual code.
2) None isn't a valid max-height property like @Reuben stated.
3) The CSS display property isn't animatable. A better way to do this might be with visibility (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property)

Comment: I did post the actual code, it is right at the bottom of the question. And I am also not trying to animate the display property, I'm trying to animate `max-height`. And it did work to animate when I set the `max-height` to `500px` instead of `none` but what I want to do now is to remove that limit completely so that it gets as much height as the content needs, like it would if `max-height` wasn't set.

Comment: Here is the version where it is `500px` instead of `none` like that in the link in my question. However, I want to make the `max-height` infinity or not set so that the height is not limited anymore by the `max-height`. https://jsfiddle.net/x84n04pa/2/

Comment: @kauffee000 @Reuben The reason why I set it to `none` is that on the w3schools website it states that that is the default value. And I wanted to have it as if it wasn't set, and the height did change correctly but simply the animation does not work. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-height.asp

Comment: You should be able to use 'unset' for that requirement.